# Should I declare a member function as `const` even if it modifies what a pointer points to?

Tags: c++, constants, public

Consider the following simple (contrived) code example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
  std::size_t size;
  char *buf;

public:
  Foo(std::size_t s) {
    size = s;
    buf = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      buf[i] = 'a';
    }
  } 

  void hexprint() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      std::cout << buf[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  char &operator[](std::size_t pos) const {
    // TODO: check pos
    return buf[pos];
  }  

  void calcSomething(int param, char *result) const {
    // calcuate something with param
    *result = 'b';
  }
};

int main() {
  const Foo foo(3);
  char *c = &foo[0];
  char result;

  // do something with c

  foo.hexprint(); // output aaa

  foo.doSomething(56, c); // upps passed in c, instead of &result
                          // still compiler was happy

  foo.hexprint(); // output baa

  // called only const functions but the const object
  // is still mutated
}
```

The member function `calcSomething` of the class `Foo` calculates something and stores the result in what the pointer `result` points to.
Now from compiler's perspective, this member function can be marked as `const`. But since it **modifies** what a pointer points to, there is a possibility that the object can be still be modified through the pointer (like shown in the example).

Now my questions are:

1. Should I qualify `calcSomething` as `const` anyway even if it modifies content a pointer points to, just because the compiler allows it?
2. Is qualifying `calcSomething` as `const` more helpful to compiler's optimization  process?
3. On the other hand, can qualifying `calcSomething` as `const` mislead the clients in thinking that it will *never ever* mutate object it is invoked on? Especially, *if it is not obvious* that there are pointers involved?
4. Is there any rules to follow when I can safely qualify a (member) function as `const`?

Comment: Qualify parameter with const like int const* result when you want to ensure that function does not modify it.

Comment: This is a very contrived example that I don't think would really crop up in practice. Passing a member variable to a member function from the "outside" is unusual an normally not possible due to *encapsulation*.

Comment: "const" does **not** mean "this function will not modify stuff". It means "this function will not modify stuff through its `this` parameter".

Comment: Related: [Declaring a function const when changing member data](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/334795/declaring-a-function-const-when-changing-member-data) at SoftwareEngineering.SE.

Comment: @Galik For what it's worth, I've updated the example to a bit more realistic example (stil very contrived though)

Comment: one question per question please

Answer (score 3):

Qualifying a member-function as `const` does not mean it doesn't have any side-effects, but that it doesn't modify its objects logical state, at least through the `this`-pointer. Just remember that the `const` applies to `*this`!

Qualifying `*this` as `const` is unlikely to have *any* effect on the optimizer. Do it if it is logically correct.

Sure there are some people who aren't clear on what parts are state of the object, or what the difference between logical `const` and physical `const` is, so some may be confused.

Anyway, are you sure `i` should be part of the public interface? That seems to be putting the *leaky* in the *leaky abstraction*.

Comment: More like putting the *not a slightest hint of* in the *abstraction*.

Comment: *"Sure there are"* - but these do not know the tools they use... If they don't know how to use a screw driver, they either should learn it or just not use it...

Comment: For what it's worth, I've updated the example to a bit more realistic example (stil very contrived though)

Comment: I've updated my example, maybe you can take another look

Comment: Well, it depends on whether `operator[]` is broken now. And what evidence there is supports that it is.

Comment: @Deduplicator obvisouly broken, but hard to spot for the reader with all those `const` promises...

Comment: @bmk *"obviously broken"* yes... The fix would be providing two index operators, a const and a non-const one. The latter easily can return the reference, the former should return a **const** reference or alternatively (in this case, as the object is small...) the content *by value*.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I qualify calcSomething as const anyway even if it modifies content a pointer points to, just because the compiler allows it?

Yes. The object itself is not modified (via `this` pointer at least!), so it is fine.

> Is qualifying calcSomething as const more helpful to compiler's optimization process?

Just because `this` is const within the current function does not mean that at the same time a non-const function is called (e. g. in another thread). So there shouldn't be too many assumptions the compiler can make from, although I cannot exclude that there are some options without peeking into the standard...

> On the other hand, can qualifying calcSomething as const mislead the clients in thinking that it will never ever mutate object it is invoked on? Especially, if it is not obvious that there are pointers involved?

const is a contract, a promise: the function declared const won't change the object called on via the `this` pointer. `this` is implicitly const within the function; still you could cast it away and and modify it anyway, but you break the contract, the promise then! And: the object could have `mutable` members - these are allowed to be changed even if the object is const...

Any further guarantees are not given by const (my thread example above, for instance), and no one should assume more than what is assured in the contract. Whoever does - own fault...

> Is there any rules to follow when I can safely qualify a (member) function as const?

Very simply: Make your function const unless you modify some non-mutable members...

---

Referring to your example:

```
a.calcSomething(56, &a.i);
```

As long as `a` is not const, this is fine, even if `a` is indirectly modified this way. The function itself just follows a pointer, and it does not matter where it points to. If `a` was const, you would not be able to call this function, as `a.i` would then be const, too, and you would try to assign a pointer to const to a pointer to non-const...

Side note: There are exceptions, but in most cases member variables represent some kind of internal state of the object and then it is not a good idea to have them public anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The rot has set in here since `i` is a `public` member. If it wasn't then you would not be able to pass `&a.i` at the calling site.

You should qualify your functions as `const` if you don't *explicitly* modify the member data in the function body.

Answer (score 0):

You are not modifiying a member in the method, hence it should be `const`. Your example is just fine, as `a` is not `const`. You would get the proper error if you tried that:

```
const A a;
a.calcSomething(56, &a.i); // yay stupid mistake isnt possible
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have updated my example, maybe you can take another look

Comment: @bmk maybe I dont want to answer a question twice ;) Note that by changing the question that much when there are already answers, you may invalidate those answers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

The argument:

```
int *result
```

Is a pointer to a external variable. So it can be modified.

In a `const` method you can not modify the internal state of the class.

```
class A {
public:
  int i{0};
  int my_result;


  void calcSomething(int param, int *result) const {
    // calcuate something with param
    *result = 42;  // Ok
    this->my_result = 42 ; /// ERROR: because the method is const.
  }
};
```